# Is the cell in an isothermal titration calorimeter open to the atmosphere?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, calorimetry

I'm just trying to understand how they can model an isochoric process.

Comment: Please include everything in the question body, which is not just an addendum to the title.

Answer (score 1):

It models an isobaric process:

> The titration is performed at constant pressure and temperature, meaning that a single ITC experiment offers data on the binding enthalpy, the equilibrium association constant and the stoichiometry, from which the entropy of binding and Gibbs energy can be computed. Hence, a single ITC experiment offers direct access to the key thermodynamic potentials related to the interaction process — Gibbs energy, enthalpy and entropy.

Source: https://www.azom.com/article.aspx?ArticleID=12258

To keep a constant pressure, you need to keep the cell open. You can limit the heat transfer by having a small opening and quickly adjusting the temperature of the reaction mixture to the ambient temperature.

The thermodynmanic parameters extracted from the raw data are Gibbs energy, enthalpy and equilibrium constant, all appropriate for an isobaric process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in my experience with a old GE-branded ITC-200 the cell is not sealed. The syringe for titration does cover a lot of the opening, but it is not sealing the cell from the atmosphere